# Show products out of stock in a category

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, categories, product

In WooCommerce I have checked the option "Visibility out of stock", but I need that some product category stay visible, even if that option is checked.

On the other hand, the main store doesn't show that category. For that I used this code:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_pre_get_posts_query' );
function custom_pre_get_posts_query( $q ) {

  if ( ! $q->is_main_query() ) return;
  if ( ! $q->is_post_type_archive() ) return;  
  if ( ! is_admin() && is_shop() ) {

  $q->set( 'tax_query', array(array(
      'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
      'field' => 'slug',
      'terms' => array( 'MYCATEGORY' ), // Don't show this category.
      'operator' => 'NOT IN'
  )));  
  }

  remove_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_pre_get_posts_query' );
}
```

As it would be possible to do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is just a quick guess, not tested but could you try starting with something like:

```
global $product;

$terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );
foreach ( $terms as $term ) $categories[] = $term->slug;

$category_to_show = ‘MYCATEGORY’;
if( $categories ) {
    if( in_array( $category_to_show, $categories ) && !$product->is_in_stock() ) {
        apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_is_visible', true, $product->id );
    }
}
```

Comment: this is for use in the loop?

Comment: You should be able to use this in a function in your functions file by removing the post->ID. 

Then you can use $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $taxonomy = 'product_cat' );

If not, try using it in the loop such as content-product.php and you can remove global product as it's already included in that file

Comment: this give me an error `Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in /functions.php on line 344` this line is this :`if( in_array( $category_to_show, $categories ) && !$product->is_in_stock() ) {` where is the error? I can't find this...

Comment: The error is because the categories array is empty and it can't iterate on NULL. Can you try wrapping the if( in array ... with if( $categories ) : if( in_array.. etc

Comment: Sorry, I'm so bad writting php. Please, can you edit the first comment with the solution? Thank you!